# Javascript onclick event doesn't work after the first click - random quote generator

Tags: javascript, html, dom-events, mouseevent

I'm building a random quote generator, when I click the 'get a quote button' it generates one of the quotes randomly, but after the first click it doesn't provide more sentences when clicked again.

hHere is my code:

html:

```
<h1>Random Quotes</h1>
<p>Press The below button to read a random quote</p>

<p id="demo"></p>
<div class="button" onclick="loopQuotes()">Get a quote</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
            
</script>
```

Javascript:

```
var quotes = [("Quote 1"), ('quote 2'), ('quote 3'), ('quote 4')];

var length = quotes.length;
var rand = Math.round(Math.random() * (length - 1));

function loopQuotes(){
    for (var i = 0; i < quotes.length; i++ ) {
        document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML = quotes[rand];
    }
}
```

Can someone kindly check and advise?

Comment: You are only generating one random number and it makes no sense to be looping....

Comment: You should put `var rand = Math.round(Math.random() * (length - 1));` into `loopQuotes()` body

Comment: You can write `i < length` instead of `i < quotes.length`.
And you don't need to bracket the quotes inside the array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As someone has already pointed out, your `rand` value is not getting generated again. Since you call `loopQuotes` methods which doesn't have the logic of generating `rand` again.

Try

```
function loopQuotes()
{
  var rand = Math.round(Math.random() * (length - 1));
  document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML = quotes[rand];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this way , because you have calling `Random` outside of function.

```
function loopQuotes(){
    var length = quotes.length;
    var rand = Math.round(Math.random() * (length - 1));
    document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML = quotes[rand];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

replace your code with below

```
var quotes = ["Quote 1", 'quote 2', 'quote 3', 'quote 4'];
var length = quotes.length;
function loopQuotes()
{
    for (var i = 0; i < quotes.length; i++ ) 
    {
        var rand = Math.round(Math.random() * (length - 1));
         document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML = quotes[rand];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's because you are generating your random variable outside of your function. Whenever you put JavaScript into an HTML page, it gets run exactly once, and only the stuff inside `function`s is available to be run at a later time. Therefore, you should put your assignment to `rand` inside your function body:

```
function loopQuotes(){
    var rand = Math.round(Math.random() * (quotes.length - 1));
    for (var i = 0; i < quotes.length; i++ ) {
        document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML = quotes[rand];
    }
}
```

In fact, it makes no sense to loop since `rand` isn't changing, so you can get rid of the `for` loop and just keep what's inside. If you meant to generate a big, long quote pieced together from multiple quotes, you'll want to do something like this in which you put the `rand` generation inside the loop body and add to the `innerHTML` string instead of replacing it:

```
function loopQuotes(){
    document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML = "";
    var length = quotes.length;
    for (var i = 0; i < length; i++ ) {
        var rand = Math.round(Math.random() * (quotes.length - 1));
        document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML += quotes[rand];
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Compynerd255 great explanation!

Answer (score 0):

Updated Fiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/3wuyo60p/

Firstly you need to generate numbers between 0 to length-1.

Secondly you dont need looping, if you plan to generate a number every time the "Get a Quote" div is clicked.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var quotes = [("Quote 1"), ('quote 2'), ('quote 3'), ('quote 4')];

function loopQuotes(){ 
var length = quotes.length; 
var max = quotes.length - 1;
var min = 0;
var rand = Math.round(Math.random() * (max - min) + min );

//console.log(rand);
document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML = quotes[rand]; 

}
</script>
```